# Console assigns different IDs to identical immutable objects

Tags: python, tuples, immutability

I'm using Python 3.10.1. When I run the following code as a `.py` file, it prints `True`:

```py
a = (1, 2)
b = (1, 2)
print(a is b)
```

However, when I type the same lines of code into the interactive Python console, I get `False`. Furthermore, when I assign to both variables on the same line, i.e.

```py
a = (1, 2); b = (1, 2)
print(a is b)
```

once again I get `True`. Is there some explanation for this behavior or is it a bug?

Comment: The `is` operator does not do the same thing as the `=` operator. You're confusing identity with equality. Immutability isn't really a consideration.

Comment: When you create a new tuple, Python does not search *every tuple previously created* to see if it's a duplicate - that would take a long time, for very little chance of doing any good.  But when when the duplicate is created in the *same compilation* (same interactive statement, or same script), the compiler can reasonably notice the duplication.

Comment: You just should not write code which cares about the identity of immutable objects. The language spec makes almost no guarantees, even calling the `tuple` constructor isn't guaranteed to give you a fresh object.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program):

> A Python program is constructed from code blocks. A block is a piece
> of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are
> blocks: **a module**, a function body, and a class definition. **Each
> command typed interactively is a block**. A script file (a file given as
> standard input to the interpreter or specified as a command line
> argument to the interpreter) is a code block. A script command (a
> command specified on the interpreter command line with the -c option)
> is a code block. A module run as a top level script (as module
> `__main__`) from the command line using a -m argument is also a code block. The string argument passed to the built-in functions eval() and
> exec() is a code block.

That's because your first code is inside a code block(a module) and it executed as a unit. But in interactive shell , when you execute them in two different commands, they are in different code blocks.

Python can re-use the reference of some immutable types like tuple inside a code block. That's just an optimization not a bug.

Let's examine it with functions(remember a function body is also a code block) and integers bigger than 256 this time:

```py
# inside a python file

def fn1():
    a = 1000
    b = 1000
    print("id of 'a'", id(a))
    print("id of 'b'", id(b))


def fn2():
    c = 1000
    print("id of 'c'", id(c))
    
fn1()
fn2()

# id of 'a' 1738701965680
# id of 'b' 1738701965680
# id of 'c' 1738701965680
```

Now:

```py
# inside interactive mode

>>> def fn1():
...     a = 1000
...     b = 1000
...     print("id of 'a'", id(a))
...     print("id of 'b'", id(b))
...
>>> def fn2():
...     c = 1000
...     print("id of 'c'", id(c))
...
>>> fn1()
id of 'a' 2441294813616
id of 'b' 2441294813616
>>> fn2()
id of 'c' 2441294813264
>>>
```

When `fn1` and `fn2` are inside a module, they are executed inside a code block but in the second one, they are not in a module, they executed separately. In `fn1` however `a` and `b` point to the same object.

Comment: Why does Python use the memory addresses of immutable objects as their IDs rather than hashing their content so that the same value always yield the same ID?

Comment: ids must be globally unique. Even if you can write a hashing algorithm that *never* outputs the same hash for two different values (impossible), if you have different algorithms for computing the ids of different types of object then how can you guarantee uniqueness? Using hashing would also be solving a non-problem anyway because you just should not care what the id of a tuple is.